# Compare 2 Columns and count results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Struggling with what i hoped was a simple task, (it's been a long day) i have the following table where locations are in Col A, and Y/N is in ColB if they have replied to feedback.

```
ColA -     ColB
Location1  N
Loc2       N
Loc1       Y
Loc3       Y
Loc4       N
Loc1       Y
```

I have created a 2nd table where i want to know how many locations have replied (Y) So the results would show Loc1=2, Loc2=0, Loc3=1

Comment: Use COUNTIFS(): https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: You have multiple locations in your "ColA" is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are counting like this. Why not just have unique location IDs in ColA and increment ColB for each feedback response?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your comments.  Basically i have several users in each location.  i guess i only need 1 response from each location, rather than each person.  So wanted to check which locations i have not had any response from.

Comment: This did it for me, Thank you @ScottCraner for the link
=COUNTIFS(D$5:D$40, "=" & "*"&$I5&"*",E$5:E$40,"=" & M$4)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842):

*[noted first in comments by @ScottCraner]*

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "=" & ""&$C1&"",B:B,"=Y")
```

**Assumptions:**

- Column `A` contains the list of locations.
- Column `B` contains the corresponding indicator based on if the location has replied to feedback
- Column `C` contains the list of unique locations
- Column `D` if where the total responses from each unique location needs to be shown

Paste the formula provided on cell `D1` and drag it down as needed.

**Reference:**

- [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)